# yii2 update query not working

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I am trying to update two tables in yii2 in users table the data is updating but in another posts table query is not updating and not getting any error also

```
public function actionUserStatusInsert()
    {  
      return  User::updateAll(['member_type' => $_POST['value']], ['id' => $_POST['id']]);
      return  posts::updateAll(['prod_type' => $_POST['value']], ['editedby' => $_POST['value']]);
    }
```

i guess i made a silly mistake out here but unable to find it can anyone figure it out?

Comment: You have 2 return statements

Comment: can't execute 2 return statements?

Comment: Return terminates the function execution, therefore what is after it is never executed

Comment: thank you i am not aware of it.

Comment: I recommend to learn PHP first before you use the Yii framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this solution.

```
     $connection = Yii::$app->getDb();
     $connection->createCommand('UPDATE posts SET prod_type="'.$_POST['value'].'" WHERE editedby="'.$_POST['id'].'"')->execute();
     return User::updateAll(['member_type' => $_POST['value']], ['id' => $_POST['id']]);
```

I Hope it will help.

Comment: @PattatharasuNataraj bad idea. In this solution you will never commit transaction. +second catch is also without sense.

Comment: this solution may work in future, i found the problem in the second query the  editedby column in not primary key that's why the db is not getting updated is there any solution for that..?

Comment: @PattatharasuNataraj Please check  my answer update now.

Comment: no ya its not working, getting internal server in ajax response